# Открыть папку программы

Tags: delphi

Как в Delphi открыть папку где расположена программа. К примеру файл 1.exe возле него расположена папка Dir2010 и при нажатии на кнопку должна открываться папка Dir2010.

Но самое главное что бы это все работало на Windows xp,7,8,8.1,10.

Comment: модуль sysUtils, ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName). Или ParamStr(0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант, можно вот так сделать - На форму бросаете кнопку и в ней код:

В uses добавить ShellApi

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ShellExecute(0, 'open', Pchar(ExtractFileDir(ParamStr(0))+ '\Dir2010'), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

Comment: А где этот uses найти ?

Comment: @Antomio_95, Смотрите :), ну в самом верху в коде вашей формы, там есть слово uses и под ним напишите "ShellApi,".

Answer (score 0):

Татьяна! С таким же успехом можно открыть папку в Проводнике! В чем суть такого программирования?
В Delphi для этого есть компонент TOpenDialog

```
    with TOpenDialog.Create(Self) do
    try
      FileName := '';
      Filter := '|*.txt'; // к примеру, нужны текстовые файлы
      Options := [ofFileMustExist, ofShareAware, ofCreatePrompt];
      InitialDir := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 
      Dir2010;  // открыть нужную папку

      .....
      if Execute then
      begin
      if FileName <> '' then
        // имя файла получено... что с ним делать дальше?
      end;  
    finally
      Free;
    end;
```